# Find files with a minimum filename length

Tags: find, filename

I'd like to find all files in a certain folder which have a filename of at least `n` characters (extension included). Is there any way to achieve this with `find`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the `find` command with a `-regex` test

```
$ find /path/to/folder -regextype posix-basic -regex '.*/.\{5,\}'
```

or

```
$ find /path/to/folder -regextype posix-extended -regex '.*/.{5,}'
```

Note that `-regex` is a *path match* rather than a *file match* - hence you need to match the leading `.*/` as well, before the 5+ character filename

Alternatively, for a pure bash solution, you could enable *extended shell globbing* and then use the pattern `!(@(?|??|???|????))` meaning 'anything that does not match one or two or three or four  characters'

```
$ shopt -s extglob
$ ls -d /path/to/folder/!(@(?|??|???|????))
```

If you want to include subdirectories, you can enable the `globstar` option as well and add a `**` wildcard i.e.

```
$ shopt -s extglob globstar
$ ls -d /path/to/folder/**/!(@(?|??|???|????))
```

for example

```
$ ls -d **/!(@(?|??|???|????))
abcde  abcdef  abcdefg  subdir  subdir/abcde  subdir/abcdef  subdir/abcdefg
```

while the non inverted matches (files shorter than 5 characters) are

```
$ ls -d **/@(?|??|???|????)
a  ab  abc  abcd  subdir/a  subdir/ab  subdir/abc  subdir/abcd
```

To unset the options afterwards, use

```
$ shopt -u extglob globstar
```

Comment: +1 Nice solutions, although they don't work for `n` as a minimum in general.

Comment: Thank you @htor - on reflection, there doesn't seem to be any reason to prefer `!(@(?|??|???|????))` over @Radu Rădeanu's much simpler `?????*` - perhaps I should delete the suggestion?

Comment: When I first saw your answer, I just skipped because it seemed too complex. Then when no other answer was working, I came back to your answer and found that I actually did not need to read `Alternatively, for a pure bash` onwards. I think if you just omit rest of the answer, you will get better response. It is just my suggestion, may be wrong.

Answer (score 11):

I think the simplest way is to use:

```
find . -name "??????????*"
```

where the number of `?` characters is equal with `n`. Is simple because is hard to forget it.

But the nicest way is to use the `-regex` option to find file names with `n` or more characters:

```
find . -regextype posix-egrep -regex ".*[^/]{n}"
```

where `n` should be a natural number (the minimum filename length).

See `man find` fore more about.

Comment: When I give `find . -regextype posix-egrep -regex ".*[^/]{n}"` it says, `find: ‘./lost+found’: Permission denied`. If I invoke the command with `sudo`, it yields no results.

Answer (score 1):

Python approach:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
from __future__ import print_function
import os,sys


def main():
    treeroot = sys.argv[1]
    base_len = int(sys.argv[2])
    for dir,subdirs,files in os.walk(treeroot):
         for f in files: 
             if len(f) >= base_len:
                 fullpath = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(dir,f))
                 print(fullpath)

if __name__ == '__main__' : main()
```

Usage is simple:

```
./find_files_len.py /path/to/top_directory/  minimal_length
```

For example:

```
./find_files_len.py /etc  5
```

That'll give us all files with basename of at least 5 characters , found recursively through `/etc/` and all its subdirectories. Note that full path of the file will be printed to the command-line

Answer (score 0):

You could loop over the list of files returned by `find` and test the length of each file's basename:

```
min_fname() {
    for path in $(find "$1" -type f); do 
        bn="${path##*/}"
        if (( "${#bn}" >= $2 )); then 
            echo "$path" 
        fi 
    done
}

# usage: min_fname dir value

$ min_fname /tmp 5
$ min_fname /home/user 10
```

This function uses only `find` and Bash builtin mechanisms, and no regex matching. Put this function definition in the `~/.bashrc` file to make the `min_fname` command persistent between logins.